# Scala extra no-arg constructor plus default constructor parameters

Tags: scala, constructor, default-parameters, scala-java-interop

I am using the Scala 2.8 default parameters on a constructor, and for Java compatibility reasons, I wanted a no-arg constructor that uses the default parameters.

This doesn't work for very sensible reasons:

```
class MyClass(field1: String = "foo", field2: String = "bar") {
    def this() = {
        this() // <-- Does not compile, but how do I not duplicate the defaults?
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is anything that I am missing.  Any thoughts that don't require duplicating the parameter defaults?

Thanks!

Comment: there's a ticket at https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4278

Comment: I spoke up in favor of that ticket at my first ever in-the-flesh scala meeting and said flesh was consumed by ravenous "don't go ruining the language with your special cases" wolves.  It's every use case for himself now!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't really recommend it, but you can do it by adding another parameter to your constructor:

```
class MyClass(a: String = "foo", b: String = "bar", u: Unit = ()) {
  def this() { this(u = ()) }
}
```

`Unit` is a good choice because you can only pass one thing into it anyway, so explicitly passing the default value doesn't allow any possibility of error, and yet it lets you call the correct constructor.

If you're willing to replicate just *one* of the defaults, you can use the same strategy except override that one chosen default instead of adding the unit parameter.

Comment: I agree that this is in the spirit of my question (minimizing duplication), but not a great practice.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

As curious work-around hack, and I do **mean hack**: you can use the internal representation of default arguments:

```
class MyClass(field1: String = "foo", field2: String = "bar") { 
  def this() =  this(MyClass.init$default$1)
}
```

Notice that it's needed to include MyClass in *this(MyClass.init$default$1)*. A partial explanation is that the default arguments are kept in companion objects.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using a factory method:

```
class MyClass(field1: String = "foo", field2: String = "bar")
object MyClass {
    def newDefaultInstance = new MyClass
}
```

Then from Java you can call `MyClass.newDefaultInstance()`

Another possibility is to move where you specify the default values:

```
class MyClass(field1: String, field2: String) {
  def this() = this(field1="foo", field2="bar")
}
```

This style is especially useful if you're working with a framework such as Spring which uses reflection to locate a 0-arg constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  In my exact case, the first wouldn't work as this is a Servlet that I am initializing (so I need the no-arg.)  The second is feasible, but I lose the pleasant defaulting behavior in tests that the default values were providing.  I would have likely turned to the first had I not needed the no-arg constructor...

Answer (score 0):

Not suitable for all purposes, but a subclass might do the trick:

```
class DefaultMyClass extends MyClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong in understanding the question, following code worked very well for me`

```
class Employee (

   ){
  def this( name :String ,

    eid :Int ){
    this();
  }
}
```

`