# Convert tuple to case class with default values

Tags: scala, tuples, case-class

```
case class Person(first: String, last: String, full: String = "blah")

val one = Person("Rachel","Green")
// one: Person = Person(Rachel,Green,blah)

val tuple1 = ("Ross","Geller")
// tuple1: (String, String) = (Ross,Geller)

Person tupled tuple1
// <console>:15: error: type mismatch;  found : (String, String)  required: (String, String, String
```

I want to convert a Tuple13 to a case class with a default value.

Comment: Sadly a **function** can not have default values like **methods**.

Answer (score 2):

Try providing an `apply` factory method in the companion

```
object Person {
  def apply(t: (String, String)): Person = Person(t._1, t._2)
}
Person(tuple1)   // res2: Person = Person(Ross,Geller,blah)
```

or perhaps implicit conversion

```
implicit def tupledWithDefaults(t: (String, String)) = (t._1, t._2, Person.$lessinit$greater$default$3)
Person.tupled(tuple1)   // res2: Person = Person(Ross,Geller,blah)
```

The strange looking `$lessinit$greater$default$3` is a hacky way of accessing defaults based on [Scala extra no-arg constructor plus default constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045863/scala-extra-no-arg-constructor-plus-default-constructor-parameters)

Comment: the tuple has 13 fields and this might look ugly. But thank you for  suggesting $lessinit$greater$default$3